# Version of ruby on rails and the accuracy of the Rails Tutorial by Michael Hartl

Tags: ruby-on-rails, railstutorial.org

I want to know if the Rails Tutorial is a wise investment now we have rails 5. I love rails, and I want to master it, but I'm a bit of conflicted with so many changes between version. Can you tell me if there is other better material to learn rails 5? Or if I have to wait to the next edition of the tutorial?

Comment: How can anyone answer whether the Hartl tutorial is a "wise investment" *for you?* That said, there's not that much difference between Rails 4 and Rails 5 on the surface. 99.9% of what you learn about Rails 4 is applicable to Rails 5.

Comment: How can anyone answer whether the Hartl tutorial is a "wise investment" for me? Well, maybe like bkunzi01 did, with respect.

Comment: *With respect*, please don't look for offense where it was neither made nor offered. Please accept my *respectful* suggestion to review the Stack Overflow [help file](http://stackoverflow.com/help) to help you identify what questions are on topic for Stack Overflow. The Q&A format is tailored towards addressing specific technical questions, as opposed to "tell me what I should do" type questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There aren't vast changes between versions however there are several big additions.  The Hartl tutorial definitely won't be a waste of time.  After it I suggest checking out ActionCable which is a major step forward for the Rails framework.

Answer (score -1):

Michael Hartl's [rails tutorial](https://www.railstutorial.org/) is definitely wise choice if you want to start learning RoR. I suggest you to start with current edition of Michael Hartl's tutorial which is built on rails 4.2.2 and later you can learn rails 5 when it is out. It will be easy to get your hands on rails 5 if you already have completed old tutorial.

Michael Hartl is already working on new edition and hopefully we receive it in short time period on [rails tutorial](https://www.railstutorial.org/). He has already updated his tutorials up to 6th chapter in [Learn Enough Society](https://www.learnenough.com/story) however it is paid though.

All the best

happy learnin.